# While Appending Image into the table using jquery path is not taking properly

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table in that somedata is there.I am implementing the search functionality in that table using ajax.It is working fine.But my problem is when i try to load the image based on path stored on the database table.It is not loading.below is my code for appending the image into table.Please any help.Thanks in Advance.

### My image path in database I have stored  like this and try to append  image path I my table using below line it showing like this

```
   Assests/images/cakes.jpeg
    $('<td>').html("<img style='width:120px;height:100px;' id='images' alt='No image' src='<?php echo base_url();?>'"+data["prod_image_path"]+">").appendTo(tr);
//the problem with this line image path is not adding to url how i can fix 
//this
 <img style="width:120px;height:100px;" id="images" alt="No image" src="http://localhost/Demo/" assests="" images="" chocolate.jpg="">
```

//This is mycode for adding image into table

```
 $(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/Demo/Productcontroller/search",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: value
            },
            success: function(response){
              var data=$.parseJSON(response);
                  if(data!=false){
                var tbody = $('#myTable tbody').empty();
                tbody = $('#myTable  tbody'),
                $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                  prop = [data["prod_name"],data["prod_group"],data["prod_maxstock"],data["prod_currentstock"]];
                  var tr = $('<tr>');
                  $.each(prop, function(i, prop) {
                  $('<td>').html(prop).appendTo(tr);
                  });
                  $('<td>').html("<img style='width:120px;height:100px;' id='images' alt='No image' src='<?php echo base_url();?>'"+data["prod_image_path"]+">").appendTo(tr);
                 $('<td>').html("<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>Productcontroller/edit/"+data["prod_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                 $('<td>').html("<a class='delete'href='"+data["prod_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                  tbody.append(tr);
            });
          }    }
  });
});
});
```

### This is my Rendered HTML

```
<div class="scrollingTable result" style="width:100%;">
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>GROUP</th>
                            <th>MAX STOCK</th>
                            <th>CURRENT STOCK</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbod>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cakes and breads</td>
                            <td>food items</td>
                            <td>1500</td>
                            <td>1700</td>
                            <td>
                                <img style="width:120px;height:100px;" id="images" alt="No image" src="http://localhost/Demo/" assests="" images="" cakes.jpeg="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://localhost/Demo/Productcontroller/edit/5">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="delete" href="5">
                                        <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>chacolates and breads</td>
                                <td>food items</td>
                                <td>1500</td>
                                <td>1700</td>
                                <td>
   //I Know the problem with this line property path is not taking correctly 
    //why Please Any help
                                    <img style="width:120px;height:100px;" id="images" alt="No image" src="http://localhost/Demo/" assests="" images="" chocolate.jpg="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="http://localhost/Demo/Productcontroller/edit/4">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="delete" href="4">
                                            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `tr.append("<img style='width:120px;height:100px;' id='images' alt='No image' src='<?php echo base_url();?>'"+data["prod_image_path"]+">");`?

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML

Comment: I will post my comple code please check.

Comment: I Have posted my rendered html please check once. Acutually my image complete path is like this  <img style="width:120px;height:100px;" id="images" alt="No image" src="http://localhost/Demo/" assests/images/chocolate.jpg="">  but it is taking like this  <img style="width:120px;height:100px;" id="images" alt="No image" src="http://localhost/Demo/" assests="" images="" chocolate.jpg="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit the Image source append text line

```
 var imgSource = '<?php echo base_url();?>'+data["prod_image_path"];
   $('<td>').html("<img style='width:120px;height:100px;' id='images' alt='No 
    image' src='"+imgSource+"'>").appendTo(tr);
```

Comment: In your code some syntax error is there I have fixed it .It is working fine now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Changed little code like below It is working fine Now.

```
var imgSource = '<?php echo base_url();?>'+data["prod_image_path"];
$('<td>').html("<img style='width:120px;height:100px;' id='images' alt='No image' src='"+imgSource+"'>").appendTo(tr);
```